# polymorphic equality in coq

Tags: coq, ssreflect

I cannot find a standard library == function which is overloaded and returns a boolean (or a sumbool, or something I can compute with). I would like to be able to do

```
3==5
```

and

```
"hello" == "hello"
```

without having to specify the type of the arguments. I would be surprised if Coq does not have this feature for equality types; could someone tell me where to find it? I have a feeling it has something to do with ssreflect but I cannot figure it out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ssreflect has the `eqType` class, which has exactly what you need:

```
From mathcomp Require Import ssreflect ssrfun ssrbool eqtype.

Check (3 == 5).
```

Most standard types have an equality operator defined in ssreflect. Unfortunately, strings are not one of them, though it is not to hard to roll up your own.  (The [Deriving library](https://github.com/arthuraa/deriving) ships with an instance, but it is not marked as stable yet.)